# How to create alias for cpp and h files (and ignoring compiler __attributes__)

Tags: c++, gcc, cuda, header, c-preprocessor

How can I create aliases for cpp and h files so that GCC can compile files of different naming suffixes?

How can I make the GCC ignore certain compiler attributes without having to wrap them in `#ifdef` and `#endif` statements?

---

### Elaboration:

I am writing a library with CUDA in which I want to be able to create the same objects both on the CPU and GPU.

If the user does not have NVCC (this is a header only library) I want the user to be able to compile with the GCC.

Is there anyway that I can make the GCC compile `.cu` and `.cuh` files while ignoring the `__host__` `__device__`and `__global__` compiler attributes without having to simply wrap all

of: 
`__host__` `__device__`and `__global__` in `#ifdef #endif` statements?

---

IE: #ifdef NVCC //have nvcc interpret `.cu` file as such

```
__host__ __device__ 
struct foo {
    foo() {/*impl*/ }
};
```

ELSE: //have GCC/Clang/etc interpret `.cu` file as such (and as an `.h` file):

```
struct foo {
    foo() {/*impl*/ }
};
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do something like this in a header file that you include everywhere:

```
#ifdef __CUDACC__ 
#define CUDAHOSTDEV __host__ __device__
#else
#define CUDAHOSTDEV
#endif
```

Then, wherever you would use

```
__host__ __device__
```

you just use

```
CUDAHOSTDEV
```

I don't know if that is any easier, but it probably is less typing if you're writing things from scratch.

You can see some CUDA-specific `nvcc` compiler defines [here](http://docs.nvidia.com/cuda/cuda-compiler-driver-nvcc/index.html#nvcc-identification-macro).

Also I'm pretty sure you can pass the `-x` switch to gcc/g++ to tell it what kind of language to recognize/use independent of the file suffix.

You might also want to look at an exising "high quality" CUDA template library like [thrust](https://github.com/thrust/thrust) to see what they do.

Comment: `-x language

Specify explicitly the language for the following input files (rather than letting the compiler choose a default based on the file name suffix). This option applies to all following input files until the next '-x' option. Possible values for language are: 
c c-header cpp-output c++ c++-cpp-output objective-c objc-cpp-output assembler assembler-with-cpp ada f77 f77-cpp-input ratfor java treelang`


Found the documentation for `-x` here:
http://tigcc.ticalc.org/doc/comopts.html

I'm gonna leave this question open a bit longer but I most likely give you best answer.

Comment: PS Thanks a ton this was a perfect solution. (I know you shouldn't say "thanks" on SO but I'm a rebel)

Answer (score -1):

You will need #ifdef / /#endif somewhere but you can often make these sorts of things look better by #defining symbols that expand to an empty value if the flag is not set:

```
#if defined(CCOMPILE_WITH_GPU)
#define MY_ATTRIBUTE xxx
#endif

MY_ATTRIBUTE void func();
```

rather than putting the #ifdef around every function declaration.